# Python: modifying single dictionary item containing an array view modifies all items

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array, namedtuple, array-view

I have two dictionaries with same keys. Each item is an ndarray.

```
from numpy import zeros, random
from collections import namedtuple

PhaseAmplitude = namedtuple('PhaseAmplitude','phase amplitude')
dict_keys = {'K1','K2', 'K3'}

J1 = dict.fromkeys(dict_keys, zeros((2,2,2,2)))
U1 = dict.fromkeys(dict_keys, PhaseAmplitude(phase = zeros((2,2)),
                                             amplitude = zeros((2,2))))

for iFld in dict_keys:
    U1[iFld] = U1[iFld]._replace(phase = random.random_sample((2,2)), 
                                 amplitude = random.random_sample((2,2)))
```

I want to modify each item in the the first dictionary using the corresponding item in the second one:

```
for iFld in dict_keys:  
    J1[iFld][0,0,:,:] += U1[iFld].phase
    J1[iFld][0,1,:,:] += U1[iFld].amplitude
```

I expect to get that `J1[iFld][0,0,:,:] = U1[iFld].phase` and `J1[iFld][0,1,:,:] = U1[iFld].amplitude` but I get `J1[iFld]` being the same for all `iFld` and equal to the sum over all `iFld` keys of `U1` (keeping track of the `phase` and `amplitude` fields of `U1` of course).

To me this looks like a bug but I've been using Python only for a month or so (switching from matlab) so I am not sure.

**Question:** Is this expected behavior or a bug?  What should I change in my code in order to get the behavior I want?

**Note:** I chose the number of dimensions of `dict_keys`, `J1` and `U1` to reflect my particular situation.

Comment: Python dict values are like pointers, I guess all keys are pointing to the same object. You can check if they are the same object using the builtin `id` function or the `is` operator. If this is the case, use the `dict.copy` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug, though it is a pretty common gotcha that shows up in a few different situations.  `dict.fromkeys` creates a new dictionary where all of the values *are the same object*.  This works great for immutable types (e.g. `int`, `str`), but for mutable types, you can run into problems.

e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = dict.fromkeys('ab', np.zeros(2))
>>> d
{'a': array([ 0.,  0.]), 'b': array([ 0.,  0.])}
>>> d['a'][1] = 1
>>> d
{'a': array([ 0.,  1.]), 'b': array([ 0.,  1.])}
```

and this is because:

```
>>> d['a'] is d['b']
True
```

Use a dict comprehension to build the dictionary in this case:

```
J1 = {k: zeros((2,2,2,2)) for k in dict_keys}
```

(or, pre-python2.7):

```
J1 = dict((k, zeros((2,2,2,2))) for k in dict_keys)
```